# Attempts to set range.x in KernSmooth's bkde2D function results in "'to' must be a finite number"

Tags: r, kernel-density, probability-density

I cannot seem to set range.x when using the bkde2D function of KernSmooth. For example, all of the following attempts result in error:

```
bkde2D(cbind((1:5),(1:5)),bandwidth=c(1,1),range.x=c(0,5))
bkde2D(cbind((1:5),(1:5)),bandwidth=c(1,1),range.x=c(c(0,5),c(0,5)))
bkde2D(cbind((1:5),(1:5)),bandwidth=c(1,1),range=c(c(0,5),c(0,5)))
bkde2D(cbind((1:5),(1:5)),bandwidth=c(1,1),range=c(0,5))
```

For all of the above, the result is

```
Error in seq.default(a[1L], b[1L], length = M[1L]) :
  'to' must be a finite number
```

This also does not work:

```
bkde2D(cbind((1:5),(1:5)),bandwidth=c(1,1),range.x=c(0,5),range.y=c(0,5))
```

However, without attempting to set the range, no error is reported:

```
bkde2D(cbind((1:5),(1:5)),bandwidth=c(1,1))
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the error message is not very helpful. The help page of the `bkde2D` function says

> range.x
>   a list containing two vectors, where each vector contains the minimum and maximum values of x at which to compute the estimate for each direction.

The only problem was to specify the argument as a **vector** and not as a **list**. The following should work

```
est <- bkde2D(cbind((1:5),(1:5)),bandwidth = c(1,1),range.x = list(c(0,5), c(0,5)))
contour(est$x1, est$x2, est$fhat)
```